# Yeoman install location always set to desktop

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I seem to be having trouble with yeoman scaffold installer.
I can cd to fresh directories which would be for the project files but for some reason using the yo starter it always installs build directories to desktop.

was working before, not sure what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `.yo-rc.json` file in a parent directory.

Delete this file and it'll scaffold into your current directory.

Yeoman is warning you when this is happening, so if you read what the tool is telling you, you'll see why your issue is happening.